# Accessing Real-Time Follower Counts via API for Various Social Media Platforms

Tags: count, streaming, real-time, social-media

**Details of My Problem:**

I am working on a project where I need to fetch the real-time count of followers for various social media accounts (in this case: Twitter, Instagram, YouTube, Twitch, TikTok, Kick, Discord). The requirement is to access this data approximately every second or as frequently as possible to reflect live updates during a streaming event.

I've explored the SocialBlade API, but it updates the follower count on an hourly basis, which doesn't meet the needs of my project. I need a solution that can provide more immediate updates to display live follower changes on stream.

**What I Have Tried:**

Contacted SocialBlade for API access, but their update frequency is limited to hourly updates.
Searched for alternative APIs that offer real-time or near-real-time data access for follower counts.
Investigated if the official APIs of the respective social media platforms provide the necessary real-time data.

**What I Was Expecting:**

I am looking for an API (or APIs) or a method that allows me to access the total number of followers of a social media account in real-time or near-real-time. The goal is to integrate this functionality into my project to provide custom live updates to the audience during streaming events.

**My Question:**

Does anyone know of any APIs or services that offer real-time or near-real-time follower count data for social media platforms? Any guidance or recommendations for a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've been looking into this as well, and from what I can tell, you would have to implement this yourself, polling each API you're interested in knowing about and for each metric, making sure to stay within their usage limits. However, implementing something like this could make it a rather valuable project, for a particular niche. 

Regardless, this will likely need to be a custom integration. I've been studying this a bit myself for the past few months, so I can go into more detail if needed.

Comment: Hi @CryptoChrisJames I'd love to talk to you more about this, I ended up doing a "rand" method to somehow simulate the follows IRL. I'll talk to you via your Twitter if you don't mind then! Thanks.

Comment: Sure, hit me up on Twitter.